# Composer install for subfolders

Tags: php, windows, composer-php, grav

Anybody knows how to `composer install` for all subfolders too? Does the composer support it? Now I need to execute this command in each subfolder or add all subfolder's `vendor` folder to git.

I found solution in Linux:
https://www.bram.us/2014/02/16/installing-dependencies-in-all-subfolder-organised-projects/

But how to do the same in Windows?

**Example.**

I have a project in `C:\grav` with `composer.json` in it.
But also I have plugins folder  `C:\grav\user\plugins` with `composer.json` in some of subfolders:

[image]

I want to execute `composer install` in `C:\grav` to install all dependencies in each `C:\grav\user\plugins\*` too.

Comment: When you run `composer install` or `composer require` it will scan through your dependencies and install them all in `vendor` there is no need to run `composer install` in each directory.

Comment: If you do need to run a script (any script) in a sub folder you can make use of composer's [script hook—manual](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md)

Comment: @Michael I mean I have `composer.json` in root and in each subfolder.

Comment: Please update your question with an example. You don't need to run `composer install` on `vendor`-folders

Comment: @Michael Example added.

Answer (score 2):

**Grav plugin or theme**

In order to support the correct installation folders for Grav plugins and themes,
you would need to add the [`composer/installers`](https://github.com/composer/installers) to the `require` section of your plugins.

Normally the plugins would land in the vendor folder, too - but, the Grav Installer tells Composer the correct position inside a Grav project, see
see https://github.com/composer/installers/blob/master/src/Composer/Installers/GravInstaller.php#L6

So, when writing plugins or themes for grav each `composer.json` must indicate the `type` as `grav-plugin` or `grav-theme`, else Composer can't match the package to the installer.

```
{
    "name": "your/some-grav-plugin",
    "type": "grav-plugin",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.23"
    }
}
```

---

**Grav main project**

Now, in your main grav project's `composer.json`, just add the plugins.

Then run `composer install`. That means the package is fetched, the composer installer is fetched, based on the package type the matching installer is triggered and the grav installer drops the file into the correct folder....

---

> But how to do the same in Windows?

Uhm... Composer works cross-platform. Not a problem.

Comment: So I need to add `type: grav-plugin` and `composer/installers` to all my plugin's `composer.json`? Also can you add main project `composer.json` example? Thx!

Comment: Yes, when you add the `type` and `composer/installers`, then all grav plugins and themes will be automatically identified and installed in the right folders. | Adding an example for main `composer.json`? There isn't much to show.. you basically add the plugins to the require section. That's it.